# How do I make my Discord bot DM users with a specific reply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot having a DM commands that can send a specific user with a specific DM message.

For example:

Me: !dm @user#6969 hi who r u

Bot: *Messages user#6969 "hello who r u"*

Currently using Visual Studio Code to code the stuff, and I don't really know how do I make this command due to I couldn't really find a working tutorial about it.

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}dm`)) {
    var mention = message.mentions.members.first()
    mention.send("hi")
}
```

Here's the error:

````
mention.send("hi")
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.client.on.message (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/index.js:69:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/Private/Desktop/Discord/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)```
````

Comment: Does message.mentions.members.first() return what you expect? Try printing it out. It's saying this is undefined.
Perhaps you could try message.mentions.members[0] instead

Comment: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/javascript-discord-bot-tutorial you'll need to fiddle around with some of their examples but the building blocks for messaging can be found here. Helped me a lot when I build my discord bot!

Comment: `message.mentions.members.first()` is undefined. There are likely no valid user mentions in the particular message it is trying to process.

Comment: but how do i custimize the "message" in getUser?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}dm`)) {
    const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!mentionedUser) return message.reply('Mention Somebody');
    mentionedUser.send('Hi');
}
```